# Need help in correctly framing problem to calculate the area $D$

Tags: definite-integrals, area

Let $D: = \{(x, y) : |x| + |y| \leq 1 \}$

How to calculate area $D$?

I've calculated it as follows and it is wrong:

I've framed the problem as $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ and $-1 \leq y \leq 1$

$\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{1} 1dxdy$

And solving this I get 4, but the correct answer is 2. How can I correctly frame this problem?

Comment: |x|+|y|<=1 does not imply that -1<=x,y<=1.

Comment: It might help to draw $D$ on a sheet of paper.

Comment: A [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8wxO.jpg) of the region $D$ should make this clear. There is dependence between $x$ and $y$, so your limits of integration should take that into account.

Comment: Yes, the picture of it made it very clear. The integrals are indeed considering the side of the square as 2, whereas the picture is making it clear that it is the diagonal of the square that is 2. So solving it for the area of a triangle and adding both sides of the diagonal gives the correct answer 2. 

Still how can I frame it with in the integrals, is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, you've got an integrand $dx\,dy=dA$.

The region you want to integrate over is $x\in[-1,1]$ and $y\in\left[|x|-1,1-|x|\right]$, which can alternatively be formulated as $x\in\left[|y|-1,1-|y|\right]$, with $y\in[-1,1]$.

This is equivalent to integrating $\left(1-|x| - (|x|-1)\right)dx=(2-2|x|)dx$ over $x\in[-1,1]$